# Efficient way to find combinations of Strings in pair of two if String is an Array

Tags: java

This is what I have so far.

```
package testproject;

public class Combinations{

      public Combinations(){

        String str_arr[]={"a","b","c"};
        GenCombinations(str_arr);
      }




      public void GenCombinations(String[] str_arr){

        System.out.println("Generating All possible Combinations for  the following "+str_arr.length+" strings.");        

        for(int i=0;i<str_arr.length;i++)
         {
            System.out.print(str_arr[i]+" ");
         }
        System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------");

        /*COMBINATIONS OF LENGTH ONE*/
        for(int i=0;i<str_arr.length;i++)
            System.out.println(str_arr[i]);        

        /*COMBINATIONS OF LENGTH TWO*/
        for(int i=0;i<str_arr.length;i++)
         {
           for(int j=0;j<str_arr.length;j++)
             {
                System.out.println(str_arr[i]+""+str_arr[j]);                   
             }
         } 

        /*COMBINATIONS OF LENGTH THREE*/
        for(int i=0;i<str_arr.length;i++)
         {
          for(int j=0;j<str_arr.length;j++)
           {
            for(int k=0;k<str_arr.length;k++)
             {  
                System.out.println(str_arr[i]+""+str_arr[j]+""+str_arr[k]);                      
             }
           }
         }
      } 


      public static void main(String[] args){

        new Combinations();
      }
    }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated..

Comment: for the string "ABCD", do you want to allow "AAA" as a three character substring? do you want to allow "CBA" as a three character substring?

Comment: I want pair of two only not three... And no duplicate strings..!!

Comment: @Raihan Jamal: Can you give an example of a correct output? Does your current code work correctly?

Comment: @RaihanJamal That's strange. It would seem from your code that you DO want length 3.

Comment: Output like ab, bc, ca etc etc. I was testing with three but I don't want three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate *all* possible substrings of length *k* from a given alphabet, then what you're doing is pretty much optimal.

If you want to generate all possible [*combinations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of length *k* from a given set (or alphabet) with *n* elements (`C(n, k)`), then a classical solution is to use *Rosen's algorithm*.

For example, given a 5-letter alphabet, if you want to take 3 combinations at a time, the gist of it is to count like so:

```
012
013
014
023
024
034
123
.
.
.
```

Here's my implementation of a [`RosenIterator` in Java](https://github.com/AlistairIsrael/jcombinatorics/blob/master/src/main/java/jcombinatorics/combinations/RosenIterator.java#L65).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want combinations of two strings, then your code is basically as efficient as you can get, with the following caveats:

- You need to be sure that the input array contains no duplicates.
- If the strings in the input array are not all of the same lengths, you *may* need to check for duplicates in the output array.